# Find matches in two text files

Tags: unix, text, awk, sed, grep

I have two files , the first I have this type of data is recorded :

```
77437234:AAAAAA    
34434342:BBBBBB     
65434343:AAAAAA      
99543545:GGGGGG
```

In the second there is a lot of data(words) that exist in the first file(for example `AAAAAA` and `GGGGGG`) , it is necessary to find a match in first file and copy them into a new final file

(need to copy the entire line of the first file)

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far, along with expected input (both files) and expected output (exactly what you want the result to look like for the given input).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `grep` to match against a word file:

```
$ cat file
77437234:AAAAAA
34434342:BBBBBB
65434343:AAAAAA
99543545:GGGGGG
$ cat words
AAAAAA
GGGGGG
$ grep -Fwf words file 
77437234:AAAAAA
65434343:AAAAAA
99543545:GGGGGG
```

To save the output in new file use redirection:

```
$ grep -Fwf words file > final
```

Options:

> -w, --word-regexp
>
> Select only those lines containing matches that form whole words.  The test is that the matching substring must either be
>   at the beginning of the line, or preceded by a non-word constituent
>   character.  Similarly, it must be either at the end of the line
>                 or followed by a non-word constituent character.  Word-constituent characters are letters, digits, and the underscore.
>
> -f FILE, --file=FILE
>
> Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.  The empty file contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.  (-f is specified by POSIX.)
>
> -F, --fixed-strings
>
> Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed strings, separated by newlines, any of which is to be matched.  (-F is specified by POSIX.)

---

If you want to match against an exact field you could use the following `awk` script:

```
$ awk -F: 'NR==FNR{words[$0];next}$2 in words' words file
77437234:AAAAAA
65434343:AAAAAA
99543545:GGGGGG
```